# CSS not changing color of first two charactor

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<p class="required">*Required</p>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.required::first-letter {
 font-size: 200%;
 color: #8A2BE2;
}
</style>
```

This css not changing color of '*' only,It changes both '*R'.Why?

```css
.required::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

```html
<p class="required">*Required</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you use ::before and then set content='*' ?

Comment: I think bart's point is that a * is not a letter.

Comment: Check this one: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/

Answer (score 3):

The `::first-letter` selector is used to add a style to the first letter of the specified selector.`*` is a symbol.

You can use `::before`

```css
.required::before {
    content: '*';
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

```html
<p class="required">Required</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the spec in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter, it says:

> Punctuation (i.e, characters defined in Unicode in the "open" (Ps),
>   "close" (Pe), "initial" (Pi). "final" (Pf) and "other" (Po)
>   punctuation classes), that precedes or follows the first letter should
>   be included. [UNICODE]

So the asterisk *should be included* (is in the "other" (Po) punctuation class of unicode) as for the spec. That's why it is included in your css.

Answer (score 0):

`first::letter` is for `letter` and `not for symbol`

so you could do that like this.

```
<p class="required"><i>*</i>Required</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.required {
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
i {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sf4ojpk8/)

**OR**

you can use `::before`

```
.required::before {
    content: '*';
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}

<p class="required">Required</p>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/80aswzuj/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the browser will apply the css style from beginning of the block to the first letter, and it doesn't think that '*' is a letter.

Why don't you use ::before and then set content='*' ?

```
        .required::before {
        content:'*';
        font-size: 200%;
        color: #8A2BE2;

}
```